# How to remove default value('0') in WicketTextField

Tags: wicket

Here iam using a wicketText Textfield component to which an Integer type is mapped, Now on load of page iam getting the '0' as default value in that textfield. How to remove that 0 from the textfield.

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `int` as the property type: that can't be `null`. Use `Integer` instead.

Comment: can you give me an example, pls

Comment: There are multiple ways to provide a value and datatype for a TextField.  If you provide your code, we should be able to suggest a modification.  The simple answer is, replace `int` with `Integer` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The TextField converts the value of the object in the model to a `String`. In case the object is `null`, the String will be empty.

You are probably using a `int` as Matrijn indicated. The java built-in primitive type can never be `null` but defaults to `0`

So use a `Integer`. (Or you could create a custom Converter, but that is just messy)

Answer (score 0):

what about using NumberTextField like this
 **NumberTextField  numberField = (NumberTextField) new NumberTextField("numberField",
                new Model(10));**

Answer (score 0):

I believe You may be using int instead of Integer. (int cannot be null, while Integer can)

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize the `Converter` of your `TextField`

```
public class Converter<C> implements IConverter<C> {

    @Override
    public C convertToObject(String s, Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        return (C) s;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(C c, Locale locale) {
            Class<? extends Object> aclass = c.getClass();
        if (aclass == Long.class) {
            return ((Long) c != 0) ? String.valueOf(c) : "";
        } else if (aclass == Integer.class) {
            return ((Integer) c != 0) ? String.valueOf(c) : "";
        } else if (aclass == BigDecimal.class) {
            return (!BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(c)) ? String.valueOf(c) : "";
        }
        return c.toString();
    }

}
```

and then, override the default `IConverter`

```
new TextField<BigDecimal>("id") {
    @Override
    public <C> IConverter<C> getConverter(Class<C> type) {
       return new Converter<C>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The generic type of text field should be a `reference`. The `Integer` is good choice. But for a good programming choice it is better to use String.The new Model("") make your text field empty.

```
 TextField<Integer> a = new TextField<Integer>("id",new Model(""));
```

you can get the integer value of your `textfield` by `a.getValue()` method.You can parse the such strings to int by  `Integer.parseInt(a.getValue());` property.

```
TextField<String> a = new TextField<String>("id",new Model(""));
```

Comment: This is just bad advice. An `TextField<Integer>` **expects** an Integer, not a String. Your second example is not how Wicket expects to be treated. Only in rare occassions you would use a textfield typed as a String field and retrieve a different type from it. Providing type safety is one of the core tenets of Wicket and you are doing everything to negate that.

Comment: I am with you Martijn. But it is because of some problems with `IntegerTextField` that I have  previously used I selected such a choices.

Comment: most software engineers try to reuse software modules. “Make or buy”
 decisions encompass more than whether a module is available;
 generally, reusing software modules is cheaper and leads to more
 robust systems. Reusing software also means you don’t have to code the
 same functionality over and over again.(**wicket in action**:manning)